# Mapbox geocoder results don't always have bounds

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I've been using Mapbox on a project with the geocoder feature. Sometimes a result from the geocoder will not have bounds defined. The event handler that fires as soon as a user selects a location from the geocoder's menu tries to zoom+center on those bounds.

The expected result would be to at least center the map onto the available latlng which is always available.

The actual result is that nothing happens. In fact, Mapbox throws an error, and because of that error, my own event handler on the select event won't fire either.

```
// Mapbox vars
var map, geocoder;

// Event handlers
function foundHandler(args){
    console.group('found');
    console.log(args);
    console.groupEnd();
}

function selectHandler(args){
    console.group('select');
    console.log(args);
    console.groupEnd();
}

// Init Mapbox
geocoder = L.mapbox.geocoder('examples.map-vyofok3q');
map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'examples.map-9ijuk24y')
.addControl(
    L.mapbox.geocoderControl('examples.map-vyofok3q', {})
    .on('found',foundHandler)
    .on('select',selectHandler)
    );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rgbk/rCjS4/1/

To reproduce

1. Search "Boston" and note the console. Results will have bounds. The custom "select" event handler will fire
2. Search "Topsail NC". results that do not have bounds. The custom "select" event handler will not fire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a bug report? That geocoding API is [in beta](https://www.mapbox.com/developers/api/#Geocoding). You may want to report your findings to support@mapbox.com.

Comment: I didn't realize it was in beta. Thanks for the info and help incanus. I sent a copy of this to support as well. The Mapbox site suggested posting problems to stackoverflow. I had a suspicion that I was doing something wrong. But yeah, the more I think about it, it's definitely a bug.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed with Mapbox.js 1.6.2.

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox.js/issues/702

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up! I heard back from support, too. Now I'm looking forward to using Mapbox :)